# string.xml Multiple substitutions specified if using % follow by string two times

Tags: android

Why is this working?

```
<string name="quantity_geoFormat">"%s"</string>
```

And this not?

```
<string name="quantity_geoFormat">"%s %s"</string>
```

For the second I am getting this error:
Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format;

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to use the positional substitution format, which looks like this: `%1$s`.

Thus your second string resource should look like this:

```
<string name="quantity_geoFormat">"%1$s %2$s"</string>
```

Comment: For the new guy out there...to grab it in code. 
geoFormat = String.format(getString(R.string.quantity_geoFormat), string1, string2);

Comment: Also don't copy the quotes if you don't want them in your output String.